# Changing the path of the generated file from dll

Tags: c#, wpf, dllimport

In a **WPF** (C#) project, I have a **Fortran** DLL file attached.

The **DLL** is located in the project directory, which goes to `Program Files` during installation.

When called, the **DLL** file generates a file in the project directory.

**Is it possible to somehow change the path of the generated file from the DLL? I cannot edit the DLL file.** (I would like to move this dll file to a location where no permissions are needed)

When the program is running as Administrator, it works. I want to use the program without Admin permissions.

Comment: Do you know how the dll finds the place it wants to write the file? There are a gazillion ways of doing that and many of them are just to find something besides the executable/dll etc. But is relevant to find a way to influence that.

Comment: @Ralf I do not know exactly. But the dll file is in `/FEM/myFIle.dll` and the generated file is in the root of the project `./`

Comment: You should fix the DLL. If you really can't, put it somewhere else so that it is able to write the file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I would like to change the path, but the `DllImport` function does not accept a variable path and I cannot hardly enter it (after installing the application, it may be a bit different for everyone)

Comment: If i understand you correctly the file is generated in your projects root. That might be a hint that it writes to the Current Working Directory. You might try changing Environment.CurrentDirectory temporarily in your app and see if the file is then generated in that directory.

Comment: It's not hard to do this. You pinvoke LoadLibrary, then call it passing the full path to the DLL to load the DLL. Do that before you call any function in the DLL. Then once it is loaded in the process, your `DLLImport("foo.dll")` attributes will resolve to the DLL that is loaded. But really, you should fix the DLL. This sort of thing is pretty intolerable. And it doesn't really make for much of a SO question.

Answer (score -1):

"Program Files" folder is read only for normal user. Your App can not generate file on this folder. You have to change path for generated file to other folder with Write rights. To user documents, temp or to hidden system ProgramData\[project] folder.
Or install application to user profile (installation per user, not per machine).

Comment: The question is how to do it. I know I can't do it the way it is. I can't move the DLL file because I can't specify the path while importing the dll.

Comment: Move whole app to user profile, if you can not change DLL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).